# Sending but not receiving mails(centOs, postfix) - Probably dns issue

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, bind

The error message:

```
Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

 contato@domain.com

Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
DNS Error: 353969976 DNS type 'mx' lookup of domain.com responded with code NOERROR
353969976 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of mail.domain.com.domain.com.br. responded with code NXDOMAIN
353969976 DNS type 'a' lookup of mail.domain.com.domain.com. responded with code NXDOMAIN
```

This is my dns zone(db.domain.com.conf):

```
;
; BIND data file for domain.com
;
$TTL    3h
@   IN  SOA     ns1.domain.com. admin.domain.com. (
                      1        ; Serial
                      3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                      1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                      1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                      1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.


domain.com.    IN   MX  10  mail.domain.com.
domain.com.    IN   A   191.222.92.24
ns1                     IN  A   191.222.92.24
ns2                     IN  A   191.222.92.150
www                     IN      CNAME   domain.com.
mail                    IN      A       191.222.92.24
ftp                     IN      CNAME   domain.com.
```

Comment: you need the mx record in your dns zone.

Comment: @c4f4t0r he already has it. OP, what does `nslookup -q=mx domain.com` return?

Comment: [root@vps0818 ~]# nslookup -q=mx domain.com
    Server:  186.202.26.26
    Address: 186.202.26.26#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    domain.com  mail exchanger = 10       mail.domain.com.domain.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

[root@vps0818 ~]#

Comment: If the file is just how it looks like in your post, just change the serial number, save and restart. If it works, I'll elaborate an answer :)

Comment: @Alex I don't know what serial number you're talking about. Can you be more directly?

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra in your DNS config file it says "Serial" and there's a "1" on the same line. Change that number, save and restart/reload

Comment: @Alex - No success... =(

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra try executing the command I mentioned before but ask a different DNS server for the answer (one that, for sure, didn't answered before), you can do that by adding the IP of another server at the end of the command. Also, DNS changes take time to actually be effective.

Comment: @SysFiend `[root@vps0818 ~]# nslookup -q=mx microsoft.com Server: 186.202.26.26 Address: 186.202.26.26#53 Non-authoritative answer: microsoft.com mail exchanger = 10 microsoft-com.mail.protection.outlook.com. Authoritative answers can be found from: [root@vps0818 ~]# `

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra not like that, you need to execute `nslookup -q=mx domain.com 8.8.8.8` being 8.8.8.8 a nameserver.

Comment: @sysfiend ok, I've done but same result.